# How to split array list into equal parts?

Tags: java, plsql, oracle10g

Is there anyway to split ArrayList into different parts without knowing size of it until runtime? I know there is a method called:

```
list.subList(a,b);
```

but we need to explicitly mention staring and ending range of list.
My problem is, we get a arraylist containing account numbers which is having data like 2000,4000 account numbers (there numbers will not be known during coding time), and I need to pass this acc nos into IN query of PL/SQL, as IN doesn't support more than 1000 values in it, I am trying to split into multiple chunks and sending it to query

Note: I cannot use any external libraries like Guava etc.. :(
Any guide in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: Can't you do `list.size()` and go from there?

Comment: list.size() will fetch the size of the list at the runtime. You need not worry about that. you can use this and split the arraylist into chunks with your desired size.

Comment: @SrinivasB, but there is no API method available right to split it based on my desired size? I need to explicitly mention range

Comment: I have posted the code to generate partitions, check it below.

Comment: @pradeepsimha: Hi, i have given my code below. check it and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for revenge downvote... !

Answer (score 77, accepted):

This should give you all your parts:

```java
int partitionSize = 1000;
List<List<Integer>> partitions = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
for (int i = 0; i < originalList.size(); i += partitionSize) {
    partitions.add(originalList.subList(i,
            Math.min(i + partitionSize, originalList.size())));
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Math.min(i + partitionSize, originalList.size() - i)`?

Comment: I think it should be ```Math.min(i + partitionSize, originalList.size())```

Comment: I've edited to match Jonathan Gawrych's suggestion.  It's less confusing than the original of `i + Math.min(partitionSize, originalList.size() - i)`(note the extra subtraction of i in there).

Answer (score 14):

generic function :

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T[]> chunks(ArrayList<T> bigList,int n){
    ArrayList<T[]> chunks = new ArrayList<T[]>();

    for (int i = 0; i < bigList.size(); i += n) {
        T[] chunk = (T[])bigList.subList(i, Math.min(bigList.size(), i + n)).toArray();         
        chunks.add(chunk);
    }

    return chunks;
}
```

enjoy it~ :)

Answer (score 9):

Java 8 (not that it has advantages):

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(list,  "a","b","c","b","c","a","c","a","b");
```

Grouping size:

```java
final int G = 3;
final int NG = (list.size() + G - 1) / G;
```

In old style:

```java
List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList(NG);
IntStream.range(0, list.size())
    .forEach(i -> {
        if (i % G == 0) {
            result.add(i/G, new ArrayList<>());
        }
        result.get(i/G).add(list.get(i));
    });
```

In new style:

```java
List<List<String>> result = IntStream.range(0, NG)
    .mapToObj(i -> list.subList(G * i, Math.min(G * i + G, list.size())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Thanks to @StuartMarks for the forgotten toList.

Comment: I think you can just use `Collectors.toList()` as the collector.

Comment: @StuartMarks I already used it a couple of times, but forgotten here.

Comment: Hmm, I think in "new style", the `3` should be `G`, no?

Comment: @FrançoisBeausoleil yes, naturellement.

Answer (score 6):

If you're constrained by PL/SQL `in` limits then you want to know how to split a list into chunks of size *<=n*, where *n* is the limit.  This is a much simpler problem as it *does not* require knowing the size of the list in advance.

Pseudocode:

```
for (int n=0; n<list.size(); n+=limit)
{
    chunkSize = min(list.size,n+limit);
    chunk     = list.sublist(n,chunkSize);
    // do something with chunk
}
```

Comment: Yes I am looking for splitting a list into chunks of size<=n, I am not getting logic to do that. Any idea would be very helpful

Answer (score 5):

If you already have or don't mind adding the Guava library, you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Simply do: `final List<List<String>> splittedList = Lists.partition(bigList, 10);`

where `bigList` implements the `List` interface and `10` is the desired size of each sublist (the last may be smaller)

Answer (score 0):

```
listSize = oldlist.size();
chunksize =1000;
chunks = list.size()/chunksize;
ArrayList subLists;
ArrayList finalList;
int count = -1;
for(int i=0;i<chunks;i++){
     subLists = new ArrayList();
     int j=0;
     while(j<chunksize && count<listSize){
        subList.add(oldList.get(++count))
        j++;
     }
     finalList.add(subLists)
}
```

You can use this finalList as it contains the list of chuncks of the oldList.

Answer (score 0):

I am also doing key:value mapping for values with index.

```
  public static void partitionOfList(List<Object> l1, List<Object> l2, int partitionSize){
            Map<String, List<Object>> mapListData = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<Object>>();
            List<Object> partitions = new LinkedList<Object>();
            for (int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i += partitionSize) {
                partitions.add(l1.subList(i,Math.min(i + partitionSize, l1.size())));
                l2=new ArrayList(partitions);
            }
            int l2size = l2.size();
            System.out.println("Partitioned List: "+l2);
            int j=1;
            for(int k=0;k<l2size;k++){
                 l2=(List<Object>) partitions.get(k);
                // System.out.println(l2.size());
                 if(l2.size()>=partitionSize && l2.size()!=1){
                mapListData.put("val"+j+"-val"+(j+partitionSize-1), l2);
                j=j+partitionSize;
                 }
                 else if(l2.size()<=partitionSize && l2.size()!=1){
                    // System.out.println("::::@@::"+ l2.size());
                     int s = l2.size();
                     mapListData.put("val"+j+"-val"+(j+s-1), l2);
                        //k++;
                        j=j+partitionSize;
                 }
                 else if(l2.size()==1){
                    // System.out.println("::::::"+ l2.size());
                     //int s = l2.size();
                     mapListData.put("val"+j, l2);
                        //k++;
                        j=j+partitionSize;
                 }
            }
            System.out.println("Map: " +mapListData);
        }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            List l1 = new LinkedList();
            l1.add(1);
            l1.add(2);
            l1.add(7);
            l1.add(4);
            l1.add(0);
            l1.add(77);
            l1.add(34);
    
    partitionOfList(l1,l2,2);
    }
```

Output:

> Partitioned List: [[1, 2], [7, 4], [0, 77], [34]]
>
> Map: {val1-val2=[1, 2], val3-val4=[7, 4], val5-val6=[0, 77], val7=[34]}

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```java
private static List<List<Object>> createBatch(List<Object> originalList, int batch_size) {
    int Length = originalList.size();
    int chunkSize = Length / batch_size;
    int residual = Length-chunkSize*batch_size;
    List<Integer> list_nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < batch_size; i++) {
        list_nums.add(chunkSize);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < residual; i++) {
        list_nums.set(i, list_nums.get(i) + 1);
    }
    List<Integer> list_index = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int cumulative = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < batch_size; i++) {
        list_index.add(cumulative);
        cumulative += list_nums.get(i);
    }
    list_index.add(cumulative);
    List<List<Object>> listOfChunks = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < batch_size; i++) {
        listOfChunks.add(originalList.subList(list_index.get(i), list_index.get(i + 1)));
    }
    return listOfChunks;
}
```

produces the following output:

```
  //[0,..,99] equally partition into 6 batch
  // result:batch_size=[17,17,17,17,16,16]
  //Continually partition into 6 batch, and residual also equally 
  //partition into top n batch
  // Output:
  [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]    
  [17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33] 
  [34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50] 
  [51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67] 
  [68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83]       
  [84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99]
```

Answer (score -2):

generic method for your help :

```
private static List<List<Object>> createBatch(List<Object> originalList,
        int chunkSize) {
    List<List<Object>> listOfChunks = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < originalList.size() / chunkSize; i++) {
        listOfChunks.add(originalList.subList(i * chunkSize, i * chunkSize
                + chunkSize));
    }
    if (originalList.size() % chunkSize != 0) {
        listOfChunks.add(originalList.subList(originalList.size()
                - originalList.size() % chunkSize, originalList.size()));
    }
    return listOfChunks;
```

Comment: Generic but lacks compile time checks when using Object instead of Java Generics