# How to persist very 100 record from List

Tags: java, hibernate, loops, jpa, persist

MY list size is consist 5000 records i need to get 100 records every time from list then persist to 100 records each time up to 5000 records persist to DB how can achieve this logic?

```
private  List<DoTempCustomers> doTempCustomers;
for(DoTempCustomers tempCustomers:doTempCustomers){
try {
    temp=new TempCustomers();               
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(temp, doTemp);
    getEntityManager().persist(temp);
}
```

my above code i was persist all 5000 records single for each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try splitting the list into parts, and then do operations on each of sublists. If you need how to split list, you can refer this link: [How to split array list into equal parts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678387/how-to-split-array-list-into-equal-parts) which gives you idea.

Comment: @PradeepSimha Probably because it's a "link only" answer. Ideally we want to see a solution here in case the link goes offline

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subList` method of `List` to get the smaller view of the `List`

```
private  List<DoTempCustomers> doTempCustomers;
//initialize doTempCustomers list
List<String> muSubList = doTempCustomers.subList(0, 100);
//this will return a view of the specified range 
//(here from 0 to 99, 0 -inclusive and 100 - exclusive) within this list
```

Refer [Javadoc for List#subList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

I solved same problem before some days ago.
my sample code to save **1000 record** each time from list rather than 500 in your case.

```
    public void persistData(){

    int tempTblCount = tempTblCount();     // 5000 in your case
    int loopCount = tempTblCount / 1000 + 1;
    int limit = 1;

    while (loopCount > 0) {

       // here i get list of data from temp table having query limit;
       List<MyCustomerVO> myCustomerList = getListFromTempTblData(limit);

       for (iterate over your list) {
              persist your record here;
       }
    }

    limit = limit + 1000;
    loopCount--;

   }

    public List<MyCustomerVO> getListFromTempTblData(int limit) {

    List<MyCustomerVO> getTempTblData = null;
    String sql = " select mobile_number,customer_no from temp_tbl limit "+limit+" , 1000 ";
    execute query;
    return list;

    }
```