# Merging two lists alternating by N elements with Stream API

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I need to merge two lists alternating by N elements from each list: taking first N elements from first list, after taking first N elements from second list, after that second portion of N elements from first list, second portion of N elements from second list and so on. If one list is longer than the other, then append the remaining elements from the longer list into resulting list.

For example, first list: `1, 2, 3, 4`,
second list: `10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17`

merging result of alternating by `N = 2` is `1, 2, 10, 11, 3, 4, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17`.

Such merging could be implemented in the following way:

```
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17);
int alternatingNumber = 2;
List<Integer> mergedList = alternatingMerge(list1, list2, alternatingNumber);


public static <T> List<T> alternatingMerge(List<T> list1, List<T> list2, int alternatingNumber) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    int size = Math.max(list1.size(), list2.size());

    for (int outerIndex = 0; outerIndex < size; outerIndex += alternatingNumber) {
        for (int innerIndex = 0; innerIndex < alternatingNumber; innerIndex++) {
            if (outerIndex + innerIndex < list1.size()) result.add(list1.get(outerIndex + innerIndex));
        }

        for (int innerIndex = 0; innerIndex < alternatingNumber; innerIndex++) {
            if (outerIndex + innerIndex < list2.size()) result.add(list2.get(outerIndex + innerIndex));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Similar merging algorithms for alternating by 1 element (alternatingNumber = 1) described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165942/write-a-method-that-merges-two-array-lists-alternating-elements-from-both-array), but I need to implement a universal logic for any alternating number.

Is it possible to do that somehow with Stream API?

Comment: Streams are not good at changing their length. So you probably should start with a stream that is long enough to hold the resulting list and *somehow* merge your elements into there via *some* kind of logic to get the correct index in the input streams based on the index in the output stream.

Comment: I you have to think too much how to do it with the Stream API, just do it with a classic loop

Comment: If you are worried about performance the stream api isn't going to magically make this better.

Comment: @rollback, I just curious is it possible to do that in a more smart way with Stream API. If not, I will stay with implementation like above.

Comment: *"is it possible to do [...] with Stream API"*? Yes, write your own `Spliterator`. --- *"in a more smart way"*? In my opinion, no.

Comment: But that really depends on what you want to do with the values in that particular order. Streams are for processing a stream of *independent* values, with the indent that processing can be parallelized without affecting result. Other than `findFirst()`, `forEachOrdered()`, `limit()`, and `skip()`, the order of values generally don't matter, and the "nearness" of values to each other definitely doesn't. So whether the two streams are merged in an alternative patter, or simply concatenated using `Stream.concat(a, b)`, shouldn't matter, if using streams. Streams are not the answer to everything.

Comment: @Andreas I wouldn't say order usually doesn't matter with streams. Any stream from a list or array is going to have a defined encounter order that constrains the merging of parallel operations, and you have to explicitly call `unordered()` to disable it. And I've seen a lot of streams used to transform lists into other lists where the order remains important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the wrap/process/unwrap pattern to encapsulate each entry with ((entryIndex / alternateStep), entry).

The wrapped elements are comparable, so when the stream is sorted by natural order, they will be sorted by their position (entryIndex / alternateStep).

In the last step, i've collected the entires stream into a List  to be returned.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class Program
{
    static <T> List<T> alternateElementsBynStep (List<? extends T> flist, List<? extends T> slist, int n)
    {
        class Wrapper implements Comparable<Wrapper>
        {
            int position;
            T value;

            Wrapper (int position, T value)
            {
                this.position = position;
                this.value = value;
            }

            T getValue ()
            {
                return value;
            }

            @Override
            public int compareTo(Wrapper o) {
                return Integer.compare(position, o.position);
            }
        }

        Function<List<? extends T>, Stream<? extends Wrapper>> wrap =
            seq ->  IntStream.range(0, seq.size())
                        .mapToObj(i -> new Wrapper(i / n, seq.get(i)))
        ;

        return Stream.concat(wrap.apply(flist), wrap.apply(slist))
            .sorted()
            .map(Wrapper::getValue)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
        ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(alternateElementsBynStep(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4), Arrays.asList(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), 2).toArray()));

        // output: [1, 2, 10, 11, 3, 4, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) provides a method `Streams.zip` which allows to process two streams element by element at once. The following code applies this method to merge two lists alternating:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> streamAlternatingInParts(List<T> first, List<T> second, int partSize) {
    Stream<Stream<T>> zipped = zip(partitioning(first, partSize), partitioning(second, partSize));
    Stream<T> alternating = zipped.flatMap(Function.identity());

    int lengthFirst = first.size();
    int lengthSecond = second.size();
    if (lengthFirst != lengthSecond) {
        if (lengthFirst > lengthSecond) {
            return Stream.concat(alternating, first.subList(lengthSecond, lengthFirst).stream());
        }
        return Stream.concat(alternating, second.subList(lengthFirst, lengthSecond).stream());
    }

    return alternating;
}

public static <T> Stream<Stream<T>> partitioning(List<T> list, int partSize) {
    int end = (list.size() + partSize - 1) / partSize;
    return IntStream.range(0, end)
            .mapToObj(i -> list.subList(partSize * i, Math.min(partSize * i + partSize, list.size())).stream());
}

public static <T> Stream<T> zip(Stream<T> first, Stream<T> second) {
    return zip(() -> StreamSupport.stream(first.spliterator(), false), () -> StreamSupport.stream(second.spliterator(), false));
}

public static <T> Stream<T> zip(Supplier<Stream<T>> first, Supplier<Stream<T>> second) {
    return Streams.zip(first.get(), second.get(), Stream::of).flatMap(Function.identity());
}
```

`partioning` according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39220959/2838289).
`zip` according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30922045/2838289).

Applied to the example given in the question:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17);
    List<Integer> alternatingInParts = streamAlternatingInParts(list1, list2, 2).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(Iterables.toString(alternatingInParts));
}
```

The output is:

```
[1, 2, 10, 11, 3, 4, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
```

Since`streamAlternatingInParts` returns a `Stream` it's possible to continue the streaming.